# center menu of dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap drop down what I'm trying to achieve is how can I center the drop-down menu to the center of the button? Right now it's being aligned to the left or right of the button based on the available space on the area. Thanks in advance.

```css
.dropdown {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
                    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `transform: translate(calc(-50% + 20px), 40px);`.

I had to add `!important` in the example, but if you have access to the code that is setting the `style` attribute on the menu, you can update the transform there instead.

```css
.dropdown {
  margin-left: 40%;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 20px), 40px) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bell"></i>
                    </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item">option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```